# How to compare two files in C++?

Tags: c++, file, compare

I need to compare two files in C++, and increase the value of a counter for each "equality" found.

My code:

```cpp
ifstream flux("C:\\Users\\Matthieu\\Desktop\\test.txt",ios::in);
char ligne[100];

ifstream flux2("base_fonctions.txt", ios::in);
char ligne2[100];

while (flux.getline(ligne, 100)) {

    bool found = false;

    while (flux2.getline(ligne2, 100)) {

        if (ligne == ligne2) {

            found = true;
            count = count + 0.5;

        }
    }
    if (found==false) {

        count = count;
    }
}

return count;
```

I would like to compare line 1 of the `test.txt` file with all the lines of the `base_functions.txt` file, line 2 of the test file with all the lines of the second file, etc.
Currently, my function constantly returns zero when there are indeed equalities between the two files?

Comment: `ligne == ligne2`  compares pointers whose are not the same, use for instance *strcmp*

Comment: Tip: This is C++. Use `std::string`.

Comment: note you reach *flux2* end of file when exiting the first time the nested *while* and never reenter in it from the second turn of the first *while*, you do not have rewind. Why limiting lines length to 100 ? As said by previous remark use *std::string* rather than C string

Comment: This code basically says "100 bytes should be enough for any line" which is a wild *assumption* that's probably going to prove itself to be painfully wrong.

Comment: Load all lines into `std::unordered_set<std::string>` from second file, then iterate over lines in first file and count matches in set. That is all. It should be less then 20 lines of code.

Comment: also you are using C++ so `std::string` should be used instead of `char[]`. In such case you would avoid this silly mistake of comparing pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparation does not work because it is not comparing the lines, it is comparing the array pointers and they are never going to be equal in this scenario. Your count should not be 0, but I suppose it is an integer and it is adding 0 to it.

To compare two lines you can use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) from `<cstring>`.

Also, this attribution it not necessary as it does nothing to count.

```
if (found==false) {

    count = count;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer
I have slightly modified the code as shown below :

Comment: ifstream flux("C:\\Users\\Matthieu\\Desktop\\test.txt",ios::in);
 char ligne[100];

 ifstream flux2("base_fonctions.txt", ios::in);
 char ligne2[100];

 while (flux.getline(ligne, 100)) {


  while (flux2.getline(ligne2, 100)) {

   if (strcmp(ligne, ligne2)==0) {

    
    count++;

   }
  }
 }

 return count;

Comment: I have see that strcmp() return 0 when my two strings are equals, but it doesn't work yet, I must have made a mistake I guess